# No logged in status on frontend nodes (domain access)

Tags: users, domain-access, subsites

I'm using [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) Module with five different Domains. On one subdomain I cannot do any changes to my templates, JavaScript files, blocks etc. If I add some code to a template or place a new block in a different region - it works only on "admin" sites. If I switch to my front page or any other node the new stuff is not there. The HTML code even says "not-logged-in" as CSS class. But when I go to .../user I am loggen in. Admin bar is also missing if I'm not on a "admin" page.

Any ideas????

Comment: Are there any load balancers or caches involved?

Comment: arg yes, thanks. I disabled boost a while ago but this site still used the cached sites from boost.